# Git rebase: resolve conflicts with merge instead of rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

In our company, the Git workflow is to delete feature branches after merge, rebase otherwise, to avoid the number of merged feature branches growing in the repo at the expense of readibility.

So if we're not interested on all the commits we did to create that feature we do a merge and then we delete the feature branch, otherwise we do a rebase on master.

Months ago a started the development of a new feature on a new branch 'feature' created from master.
Now, for the reasons described above, I would like to rebase, to keep all the history of commits for that feature.
But during feature developments, master diverged so much that I'm fixing, one after the other, an incredible number of conflicts for about 400 commits (I'm more or less 400 commits ahead and 400 behind master): it's a nightmare, a very error prone procedure.

Instead, what I like most of merge, is that I fix conflicts once.

I'm sure I'm missing something since I'm a Git beginner, but is there a way to solve all the conflicts like I normally do with merge then apply the rebase operation?

Comment: I don't think there is a silver bullet fix for this.  Part of rebasing is replaying your commits on top of the new commits coming from `master`, and this can lead to conflicts.  The best solution here, assuming you want to use rebase, is to do it more often, so that you don't end up with a 400 commit divergence from `master`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I understand, I was thinking about a merge of master into feature branch, and then a "forced" rebase on master with the assumption that the last commit on feature branch fix all the previous conflicts. But I'm sure I'm missing something...

Comment: Here is the problem with that: Then you'd have 400 commits with unresolved merge conflicts.  It would largely defeat the purpose of a rebase, which is to keep a linear, functional, history of your project.  Instead, in the worst case scenario you might have broken commits in some places, that would not even build.

Comment: Depending on the host of your Git repository you maybe have the option to do a squash merge. This would "squash" your 400 commits into one commit which would be added to the top, keeping a linear history, which is probably what your team is aiming with the rebasing. But you'll have the disadvantage to lose the history (which might not be that useful in the long run).

Comment: Either you've left something important out of your described workflow, or there's a major misconception underlying your question.  If you merge and then delete a branch, the original commits are still present.  Do you perhaps mean that you're "squash merging" when you don't care about the history?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: I understand your point. I know commits are not deleted but the git graph keeps the feature branch and we would like to have a "linear" graph, that's why rebase is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase` replays commits one by one. There is nothing which allows you to "resolve conflicts only once". Every single commit that is being replayed has a chance of conflicting with previous changes and you have to resolve those conflicts.

If you want to resolve only once, perform a `git merge` – the conflict resolution will be in the merge commit itself and each side of the merge can be built standalone.